# Can I fit normal kenwood bowls in the major series

Tags: equipment

I have a Kenwood Chef Major and while it's great, I find the mixing bowl to be a bit on the large size for simple jobs. I'm wondering if there is any reason why I wouldn't be able to fit a normal chef size bowl.

Anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put regular ceramic bowls under my mixer before (also a Kenwood, but that doesn't really matter.)

The only things you have to look out for are:

1. Does the paddle scrape the bottom? If so, raise it up until it doesn't (paddle height is adjustable.)
2. Does the paddle hit the sides as it rotates? If so, your bowl is not wide enough. Get a wider bowl.

If you were mixing a very small amount, you might find that, due to the angle of the curve of the bowl, it is not optimum in getting everything amalgamated, but for the most part, a bowl is a bowl. Just like with the supplied bowl, you probably have to scrape sides every now and again to make sure everything's mixing together anyway.

**TL;DR:** a bowl is a bowl, just don't let the paddle hit it, because, well, the paddle is hitting it (if you needed a reason.)

Comment: Wow, you Kenwood customers are lucky! My mixer is a Bosch, its bowl has to fit into its socket with a click, and if it hasn't done so, none of the attachments can be turned on (not even the ones which don't require a bowl). It's annoying when the bowl is already in use and I have to do something else.

Comment: @rumtscho it sounds like engineering safety: bowl must be firmly, properly fitted to socket, or it might come loose and fly around while mixing? In contrast, I can even turn the handle to lift up the arm, and the whisk will keep going, splattering whipped cream everywhere. Not sure which is better :P